# Como recorrer un string con saltos de linea y agregar texto en Excel

Tags: excel, foreach

Lo que quiero hacer es que por cada salto de linea en una celda, agregar "&0A" al final de la linea. Se me ocurrio un **for Each** pero no se como reconocer los saltos de linea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede usar la función [split](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) para generar una array con cada una de las lineas del texto, para esto es necesario usar como delimitador la constante [chr(10) o vbLf](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Des-ES%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1092146)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) en la función split.

Una vez que se tiene el array, puede usar un ciclo for para recorrer cada linea y agregar al final lo que usted necesita.

seria algo como esto.

```
Sub TestSeparaLineas()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim data() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    txt = wsReportes.Range("A1")

    data = Split(txt, vbLf)

    For i = 0 To UBound(data)
        Debug.Print data(i) & "&0A"
    Next i
End Sub
```

El código anterior toma el texto que esta en la celda A1 de la Hoja1 e imprime en la ventana inmediato cada linea con "&0A" agregado al final de cada una.

En lugar de imprimir con Debug.Print, puede pasar los datos a filas de alguna hoja o agregarlos a otro array, esto ya depende de lo que finalmente hará con estos datos.